# How to code a very simple login system with java

Tags: java, authentication, passwords, system

I need to create a system that checks a file for the username and password and if it is correct, it says whether or not in a label. So far I have been able to simply make one username and password equal to the variable, but need to link it to a file somehow. I am a noob programmer so lots of help is appreciated. Here is what I have under my authenticate button.

```
String pass;
String user;
user = txtUser.getText();
pass = txtPass.getText();

if(pass.equals("blue") && user.equals("bob") ){
    lblDisplay.setText("Credentials Accepted.");
}
else{
    lblDisplay.setText("Please try again.");
}
```

Comment: is it a web application or a desktop one?

Comment: So what have you tried with reading from a file?

Comment: like I said, I am pretty bad at programming so I don't really know how to link this to a file at all, this is a desktop one, just using netbeans.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to use `java.util.Scanner` for this issue.

Here is a good login program for the console:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // I use scanner because it's command line.

public class Login {
public void run() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File("the\\dir\\myFile.extension"));
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    String user = scan.nextLine();
    String pass = scan.nextLine(); // looks at selected file in scan

    String inpUser = keyboard.nextLine();
    String inpPass = keyboard.nextLine(); // gets input from user

    if (inpUser.equals(user) && inpPass.equals(pass)) {
        System.out.print("your login message");
    } else {
        System.out.print("your error message");
    }
}
}
```

Of course, you will use `Scanner scanner = new Scanner (File toScan);` but not for user input.

Happy coding!

As a last note, you are at least a decent programmer if you can make Swing components.

Comment: thank you so much, and haha idk if that makes me decent that is just how my teacher taught me so w/e

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoginMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String Username;
    String Password;

    Password = "123";
    Username = "wisdom";

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Username : ");
    String username = input1.next();

    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Password : ");
    String password = input2.next();

    if (username.equals(Username) && password.equals(Password)) {

        System.out.println("Access Granted! Welcome!");
    }

    else if (username.equals(Username)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Password!");
    } else if (password.equals(Password)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Username!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Username & Password!");
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my first code on this site try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BATM {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String username;
    String password;

    System.out.println("Log in:");
    System.out.println("username: ");
    username = input.next();

    System.out.println("password: ");
    password = input.next();

    //users check = new users(username, password);

    if(username.equals(username) && password.equals(password)) 
        System.out.println("You are logged in");



}

}
```

Comment: Username and password have not been defined, so this will cause NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code :

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {

    String username ;
    String password;
    String yes_0r_no;
    String scann;
    String passscan;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Username:");
    username = name.next().toLowerCase();

    Scanner pass = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Password:");
    password = pass.next().toLowerCase();


    System.out.println("You are logged in");

    Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Do you want to check this or not(yes or no) :");

     yes_0r_no = ask.next().toLowerCase();



    while (true){
        if (yes_0r_no.equals("yes")){
            System.out.println("Username:");
          scann = scan.next().toLowerCase();
          if (scann == username) {
              continue;
          }
        System.out.println("Password");
        passscan = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
        if (passscan.equals(password)) {
            System.out.println("You are logged in");
            break;

        }if (!password.equals(passscan)) {
            throw new IllegalAccessException();
            }
        }

        if (yes_0r_no.equals("no"))
            break ;



    }


}
```

}

Comment: Use this code and try this out. I didn't find a short answer but it is working great.This is a very easy code that you can understand it ,just by seeing it

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoginMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String Username;
    String Password;

    Password = "123";
    Username = "wisdom";

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Username : ");
    String username = input1.next();

    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Password : ");
    String password = input2.next();

    if (username.equals(Username) && password.equals(Password)) {

        System.out.println("Access Granted! Welcome!");
    }

    else if (username.equals(Username)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Password!");
    } else if (password.equals(Password)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Username!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Username & Password!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, String> d = new HashMap<>();

void input(String u, String p, String e) {
    read();
    if (e.equals("login")) login(u, p);
    else if (e.equals("register")) register(u, p);
    write();
}

void read() {
    d = new HashMap<>();
    String s = "";
    try {
        s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("data.txt")));
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String [] pairs = s.split("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        d.put(pairs[i].split(",")[0], pairs[i].split(",")[1]);
    }
}

void write() {
    try (FileWriter m = new FileWriter("data.txt")) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : d.entrySet()) {
            m.write(entry.getKey() + "," + entry.getValue() + "\n");    
        }
        m.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

boolean login(String u, String p) {
    return (d.get(u).equals(p)) ? true : false;
}

boolean register(String u, String p) {
    if (d.containsKey(u)) return false;
    d.put(u, p);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hint:
 1. [String.Contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
 2. [File Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: "Hints" especially this brief should be posted in the comments form, because they are not answers.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am not providing a complete answer for the fact that this is definitely a programming assignment, and providing the complete answer would be plain cheating. He should learn by knowing about the class and different methods.

Comment: That's fine, but if you want to do that you should use the comment form rather than the answer form.

Answer (score -2):

One way you could do it is have a file with the username and pass directly under it. Then uses the Scanner class and when you create it, make the file the parameter for the Scanner. Then use the methods hasNext(); and nextLine to verify the username and password;

```
String user;
String pass;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("File.txt"));

while(scan.hasNext){ //While the file still has more lines remaining
     if(scan.nextLine() == user){
          if(scan.nextLine == pass){
                   lblDisplay.setText("Credentials Accepted.");
          }
          else{
               lblDisplay.setText("Please try again.");
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: You must use the .equals() method on strings rather than the `==` operator.  Also, this logic will fail in interesting ways if anyone's username happens to be someone earlier's password.

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.<span class="q39pbqr9" id="q39pbqr9_9">net</span>.*;
import java.io.*;

<span class="q39pbqr9" id="q39pbqr9_1">public class</span> A
{
    static String user = "user";
    static String pass = "pass";
    static String param_user = "username";
    static String param_pass = "password";
    static String content = "";
    static String action = "action_url";
    static String urlName = "url_name";
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            user = URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8");
            pass = URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");
            content = "action=" + action +"&amp;" + param_user +"=" + user + "&amp;" + param_pass + "=" + pass;
            URL url = new URL(urlName);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)(url.openConnection());
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(content);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String responeLine;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            while ((responeLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                response.append(responeLine);
            }
            System.out.println(response);
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
```